# SQL Server: How to make a query with a left outer join + dependent inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm facing with a join problem in sql server 2005 database.
I've the following tables structure:

```
 TableA --LEFT JOIN--> TableB --INNER JOIN-->TableC
```

So if I write a query like this:

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.keyOfB = TableB.key
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableB.keyOfC = TableC.key
where TableA.key = aValue
```

it read 0 record if there's not any `TableB` record associated with `TableA` record.
But `TableB` is in outer join, so this is not what I expected. In other words, the INNER JOIN shouldn't have been considerer because there's not any `TableB` record!
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the order of JOIN operations.

The result of (A LEFT OUTER JOIN B) INNER JOIN C,  you want A LEFT OUTER (B INNER JOIN C).

Try dropping some () in there.

Or try reordering your JOINS to ... B INNER C RIGHT OUTER A to get (B INNER C) RIGHT OUTER A.

EDIT:
Example of what I was thinking:

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (TableB INNER JOIN TableC ON TableB.keyOfC = TableC.key) 
ON TableA.keyOfB = TableB.key
WHERE TableA.key = aValue
```

Flipping to RIGHT OUTER:

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableB 
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableB.keyOfC = TableC.key
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableA ON TableA.keyOfB = TableB.key
WHERE TableA.key = aValue
```

NOTE: Forgive me if this is doesn't work, I haven't touched SqlServer since version 7.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual table for (B+C) join.
EDIT: Something like:

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (select key from TableB INNER JOIN TableC ON TableB.keyOfC = TableC.key) as TableBC 
   ON TableA.keyOfB = TableBC.key
where TableA.key = aValue
```

Comment: Can you modify Pier Luigi's code with your suggestion because I'm not sure what you mean here?

Comment: +1 - I didn't really get what OP needed at first but I think this cuts to the point.  Once grouped as you suggest, only Record A is 'necessary', the fields from B and C will follow if they BOTH match.

Comment: It's not quite as easy as adding a few parens, it takes a little reordering and probably a new SELECT, unless if there is something clever im missing (always very possible =P)

Comment: i think the query is intended to be read as "for each tablea row, possibly the corresponding row from tableb and if that's found, definitely the row from tablec". TBH I usually simply write all inner joins dependent on an outer join as themselves an outer join to work around this, which if the tableb/tablec link is constrained so that tablec row is always present, then makes no real difference even if it's not strictly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is behaving exactly as it should. Your link with TableC is through TableB so the link will not be connected if no TableB record.

Changing `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER` as well - although it is really an inner as far as the data concerned.

Answer (score 1):

If you run query without INNER JOIN, there will be all records with TableB.key null, right? So next INNER JOIN can't find any matching record, that's why there is no result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code as an example of using left out join for both table b and c.

```
declare @TableA table (Adata1 char(2), Adata2 char(2))
declare @TableB table (Bdata1 char(2), Bdata2 char(2))
declare @TableC table (Cdata1 char(2), Cdata2 char(2))

;Insert @TableA 
Select 'A', 'A' union all
Select 'B', 'B' union all
Select 'C', 'C'

;Insert @TableB 
Select 'Ab', 'Ab' union all
Select 'B', 'B' union all
Select 'C', 'C'

;Insert @TableC 
Select 'A', 'A' union all
Select 'B', 'B' union all
Select 'Cb', 'Cb'

--Select * From @TableA
--Select * From @TableB
--Select * From @TableC

Select * from @TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN @TableB on Adata1 = Bdata1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @TableC on Bdata1 = Cdata1
```

Results are:

```
Adata1  Adata2  Bdata1  Bdata2  Cdata1  Cdata2
A            A  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
B            B  B   B   B   B 
C            C  C   Cb  NULL    NULL
```